# Unity Fog looks different on Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

The fog from my 3d game looks good in Unity (Desktop) but on Android the fog looks different? Can anyone explain the reason?

PC Unity:

[image: PC Unity]

Android:

[image: Android Unity]

Answer (score 1):

There are few settings, which you have to check first.

1. Project Settings/Quality: make sure that your editor quality is same as your Android build.
2. Project Settings/Player/Other Settings: Color Space and Graphic APIs

According to your android screenshot, you also have color bending issue. And you have different gamma value on displays too.

Answer (score 0):

Oversized scaled cubes/low vertex objects often cause issues on mobile

The solution would be cutting/separate the cube into more small cubes or add even more vertexes to the cube

[Here is the thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/linear-fog-bug-on-mobile.971454/) I found this reference from